# how to use checkbox checked on html-el:checkbox in struts

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox, struts-1

I want to use checked attribute on html-el:checkbox in struts. But there is no attribute for that. When i use checked="checked" the page is blowing up..Is there any alternative to check whether checkbox is checked,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set value="true"

Answer (score 0):

There is no checked attribute for html el checkbox. So we need to use javascript for that which i figured it out. Thanks for the reply anyways